# Check if object with same properties exist - Static factory method

Tags: java, static-methods

Using static factory method, I want to create objects (e.g. persons), but throw an error/exception if a person with the same criteria is being created.

I have 2 classes Person.java / Program.java (<-Main)

My static method is as follow:

```
public class Person{
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  private Person(String firstName, String lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  public static Person fullName(String firstName, String lastName){
     /*if(firstName.equals(this.firstName)){
        System.out.println("Person already exists!");
     }else{
       return new Person(firstName,lastName);
     }*/
     return new Person(firstName, lastName);
  }
}
```

Now obviously the commented-out part wouldn't work because *Person* isn't instanciated, but I'm kind of lost about how I could go on.

And yes, I'm overriding equals and hashcode!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve it you should keep traces of all created instances in the `Person` class by using a `static` collection.
Note that it may cause memory retention if you don't use weak references for them and these are only referenced by the collection defined in `Person`.

Then about the check of an existing `Person`, as you overrided `equals()` and `hashCode()`, you could create a new `Person` from the parameters and check whether it was already created.

```
public class Person{
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  private static Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<>();

  private Person(String firstName, String lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  // equals and hashCode overrided relying on firstName and lastName fields
  //   ..

  // Aditionnally to ease the creation of the exception message, override toString() too
  @Override
  public String toString(){
      return "name=" + name +", lastName=" + lastName);
  }

  public static Person fullName(String firstName, String lastName){
     Person p = new Person(firstName, lastName);
     if (persons.contains(p)){
       throw IllegalArgumentException("person " + p " already created";
     }
     persons.add(p);
     return p;
  }

}
```

Comment: It should be mentioned,
that you also need to override the `toString()` method
(relying on `firstName` and `lastName` fields)
so that the thrown exception will have a meaningful message.

Comment: It would be better to use concurrent version of Set to use your class in multithread code. For example using Java 8 you can achieve this by `Set<Person> persons = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`

Comment: @ Dmitry Gorkovets Indeed. But the multithreading is not a requirement here.

Comment: Or even simpler, `if (!persons.add(p)){ throw IllegalArgumentException("person " + p " already created"; } return p;`

Comment: This solution is good for complex objects. For simple objects like person you should rather hash the firstname and lastname and save the hash in a set instead of the whole person. Spares memory and you don't have to change the persons equals method. Else you depend on it and it can't be used for other stuff where it might be necessary. hashCode() would do that for you.

Comment: @Basti "save the hash in a set instead of the whole person."  You could have Hashcode collisions. So you should finally use more complex code. Besides, premature optimization should be avoided. About the `equals()`/`hasCode()` methods overriding, these are an OP information. It is not said the reason of them and I don't prejudge about it.

Comment: @davidxxx as i said yours is good for complex data. for easy data like person it would be better to optimize for memory and comfort reasons. Just trying to mention all possibilities for the op. Your solution is defenetly the common way to go. The op probably also wont just stick with that easy objects in the end